# Formatar data Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou com um problema na hora de passar uma data para um select. Usando a forma abaixo, o select me retorna normalmente os dados:

```
SELECT H.* FROM HORARIOS H
                     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                           SELECT * FROM RESERVAS R
                                WHERE H.COD BETWEEN R.COD_HORA_SAIDA AND
                                      R.COD_HORA_PREVISTA-1 AND
                                      R.COD_VEICULO = 1 AND
                                      R.DATA_SAIDA = '2015-11-26')
                                ORDER BY H.COD;
```

Mas, se eu tento passar para o formato d-m-a da forma abaixo, ele não retorna corretamente os dados.

```
SELECT H.* FROM HORARIOS H
                     WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                           SELECT * FROM RESERVAS R
                                WHERE H.COD BETWEEN R.COD_HORA_SAIDA AND
                                      R.COD_HORA_PREVISTA-1 AND
                                      R.COD_VEICULO = 1 AND
                                      DATE_FORMAT(R.DATA_SAIDA, '%d-%m-%Y') = '26-11-2015')
                                ORDER BY H.COD;
```

Alguém saberia me dizer porque desta forma ele não aceita?

Comment: Não seria apenas DATE_FORMAT(R.DATA_SAIDA,'%m-%d-%Y') =  26-11-2015' para que esse ultimo ) ?

Comment: o último é o parâmetro que vem do PHP. Ele vem nesse formato dd-mm-aaaa

Comment: No primeiro exemplo esta R.DATA_SAIDA, NO SEGUNDO APENAS DATA_SAIDA, esta certo isto ?

Comment: Foi um erro de digitação, já corrigi.

Comment: Que bom que deu certo!